# Linked list reverse function leads to infinite printing loop

Tags: c, linked-list

I was writing a C code to reverse a link list. I got into one problem.
If I do not make my `next` pointer `NULL` my reverse function works fine, but if I make it null the linked list always keeps printing in the while loop.

Below is the correct program, which works fine.
But if I make `*next = NULL`, the display function will keep printing in the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *head;

/*************************************************************/
/*                                                           */
/*  create - Function to create Nodes and add them at last   */
/*                                                           */
/*************************************************************/
int create(int data)
{
    struct node *temp,*ptr = NULL;
    //int data = 0;

    ptr = head;

    //Printf(" Enter the Data for Node : ");
    //scanf(" %d ", data);  

    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        // this is the first node
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->data = data;
        head = temp;
    } else {
        // this is not the first node
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            if (ptr->next == NULL) {
                temp->next = NULL;
                temp->data = data;
                ptr->next = temp;
                break;
            }
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/*************************************************************/
/*                                                           */
/*  create_in_front - Function to add Node in Front          */
/*                                                           */
/*************************************************************/
int create_in_front(int data)
{
    struct node *temp,*ptr = NULL;
    ptr = head;

    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        // this is the first node
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->data = data;
        head = temp;
    } else {
        // this is not the first node
        temp->next = ptr->next;
        temp->data = data;
        head = temp;
    }
    return 0;
}

/*************************************************************/
/*                                                           */
/*  create_in_between - Function to add Node in between nodes*/
/*                                                           */
/*************************************************************/

int create_in_between(int data,int pos)
{
    struct node *temp, *ptr = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    ptr = head;

    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;

    for (i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        if (i == pos-1) {
            temp->next = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = temp;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}


/*************************************************************/
/*                                                           */
/*  delete_in_between - Function to add Node in between nodes*/
/*                                                           */
/*************************************************************/

delete_in_between(int pos)
{
    struct node *ptr, *prev = NULL;
    ptr = head;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        if (i == pos-1) {
            prev = ptr->next;
            free(ptr);
            break;
        }
        prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

/*************************************************************/
/*                                                           */
/*  reverse - Function to reverse link list                  */
/*                                                           */
/*************************************************************/

int reverse()
{
    struct node *prev = NULL;
    struct node *curr = head;
    struct node *next = NULL;

    curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    head = prev;

    return 0;
}

/*************************************************************/
/*                                                           */
/*  display - Function to diplay link list                   */
/*                                                           */
/*************************************************************/
// Function to display Link List
int display()
{
    struct node *temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d->",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    create(10);
    create(20);
    create(30);
    create(40);
    create(50);
    create_in_front(34);
    create_in_between(55,2);
    //delete_in_between(4);
    reverse();
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Let me know the logic behind this.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to post the non-working code too. It's difficult to say why it's wrong when we can't see it. I.e. *where* do you set `next` to `NULL`? Or are you actually doing `*next = NULL` somewhere??

Comment: "But if I make *next = NULL, the display function will keep printing in the while loop." where?

Comment: Please show us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated!! please see the code above

Comment: In my opinion. initializing _next_ in reverse() to NULL cannot make a difference at all, since it is set at the beginning of the while-body anyway.

Comment: If you had commented out the `create_in_front` and `create_in_between` function calls, you would see that there's nothing wrong with the `reverse` function.

Comment: This comment seems misleading: *'delete_in_between - Function to add Node in between nodes'*

Comment: Debugger.........................DCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `create_in_front()` is bogus: `temp->next = ptr->next;` should be changed to `temp->next = ptr;`

`create_in_between()` does not handle the case of `pos==0`.

`delete_in_between()` is completely dysfunctional: the node is frees but its predecessor still points to it.

`reverse()` seems correct to me, it could be simplified this way:

```
int reverse() {
    struct node *prev = NULL;
    struct node *curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        struct node *next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    head = prev;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem seems unrelated to your modifying the `reverse()` function, maybe a side effect of bugs in the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `reverse()` function seems correct, but the rest of the code is somewhat overcomplicated. Try something like this:

```
void create(int data) {
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (temp != NULL) {
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->data = data;

        if (head == NULL) {   // this is the first node
            head = temp;
        } else {
            // this is not the first node
            struct node *last = head;

            while (last->next)
                last = last->next;

            last->next = temp;
        }
    }
}

void create_in_front(int data) {
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (temp != NULL) {
        temp->next = head;
        temp->data = data;
        head = temp;
    }
}
```